# How to hide UIPickerView in uitextfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I created a `UITextField` and I set this inputview a pickerview. If I click into the textfield the pickerview is showing, but if I don't want to change the pickerview value, I tried to click on the view to dismiss pickerview, but its not working...
I set textfield inputview in viewDidLoad():

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;
self.pickerTF.inputView = picker;
```

pickerTF is an UITextfield and picker is an UIPickerView.

I tried to use these methods to dismiss pickerview:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return true;
}
-(BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal{
return NO;
}
```

I have already edited .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, NetworkManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a tap gesture recognizer to the textfield's super view and call `endEditing:` on the super view.

Comment: thanks, i found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456120/hiding-the-keyboard-when-losing-focus-on-a-uitextview