# Implementing UITextField programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I am not getting the behavior I expect out of a text field.  Previously, I have instantiated textFields via storyboard or Xib.  When I click within the textfields bounds it becomes first responder and when I click outside it resigns first responder.

This isn't the case when I create it programmatically within this void method.  I tried emulating the behavior by setting textfield to first responder with a uiTextFieldDelegate method but not actually fire when clicking in the textfield.

```
- (void)createTextField {
    self.searchField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 250, 35)];
    self.searchField.delegate = self;
    //[self.searchField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.mapView addSubview:self.searchField];
    self.searchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.searchField.placeholder = @"type here";
    self.searchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.searchField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.searchField.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding the Keyboard when losing focus on a UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456120/hiding-the-keyboard-when-losing-focus-on-a-uitextview)

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` does not resign the first responder when tapping outside. You have to do that programmatically like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456120/hiding-the-keyboard-when-losing-focus-on-a-uitextview) or have another `UIResponder` become the first responder.

Comment: the main problem I am having is that the text field does not become first responder when tapped.

Comment: i found the bug.  It was to do with Google Map view.  As per googles instructions I was setting the map view to my view controller's view like:  self.view  = self.mapView.  Somehow, when adding my textfield as a subView either to self.view, or self.mapview (either should be ok?) it was breaking the textfields behavior.